# Populate PDF fields .NET

Tags: .net, pdf

Does an open source .NET library exist that can be used to populate PDF fields? I have a PDF template with several text fields that I need to populate then stream the populated PDF via HTTP.

Comment: Please specify whether those *text fields* are ActoForm fields, XFA fields, or merely some lines and boxes appearing like a field.

Comment: In that case any general purpose PDF library should do. By the way, you say you want *an open source .NET library* - is open source (i.e. you can inspect the sources) really the important part our do you actually mean a free-to-use one?

Comment: Free to use ideally yes

Comment: In that case you should mention the licenses acceptable for you. LGPL? GPL? AGPL? MPL? ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on http://pdfclown.org/. It's free as in speech and free as in beer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems iTextSharp will do the trick: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001747/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030211-1.aspx